# formatting sqlite read data from db to match textview columns

Tags: android, sqlite, layout, android-layout

I have a sqlite db I'm using to store my info and I have four column headings weighted out to '1'.  I have a problem reading the data as it bunches it all up in the middle and covers up one of my column headings.  What am I doing wrong or is there another way I should be displaying the information?  Thanks

Here is the code:

here is the view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Hair Wash" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Comments" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="get info from db" />
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the view java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bathreport);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        MyDBAdapter info = new MyDBAdapter(this);
        info.open();
        String data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);
    }
```

My adapter's getdata

```
public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { /*KEY_ROWID,*/ KEY_BATHDATE,
                KEY_BATHTIME, KEY_HAIRWASH, KEY_COMMENTS };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "\n";
        //int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BATHDATE);
        int iTime = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BATHTIME);
        int iHair = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HAIRWASH);
        int iCom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMMENTS);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iDate)
                    + " " + c.getString(iTime) + " " + c.getString(iHair) + " "
                    + c.getString(iCom) + "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a better implementation is to use a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

The layout above should contain 4 TextViews in one Horizontal Linear layout (similar to your Table row implementation), the from is your column names and the to is the Ids of the 4 TextViews

Then set this adapter as the adapter of a ListView that should replace your Table